# Dealing with determinants of $n\times n$ matrices!

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, determinant

> Let $\omega$ be a complex cube root of unity with $\omega\ne1$ and P=$[p_{ij}]$ be a $n$ x $n$ matrix with $p_{ij}$=$\omega^{i+j}$. Then $P^2\ne$O (null matrix), when $n=$
>
> a) $57$
>
> b) $55$
>
> c) $58$
>
> d) $56$

In this question, one thing I know is the determinant of $P$ will be zero if a row or a column repeats, for which the number of columns should be a multiple of $3$. However, is this condition sufficient for $P^2\ne0$? This is indeed giving me the answer as b,c,d, which is correct however my solution doesn't seems convincing enough.

Before answering (if you know the correct solution), please give a hint in the comments first. I will like to try it myself, and reach out to you if I was able to do it.

Comment: No power of $P$ will ever be zero.  Do you mean $\det P^2 \neq 0$?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Sorry, I updated my question.

Comment: For googling purposes, such a matrix (which has constant cross-diagonals) is known as a [Hankel matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_matrix). They arise in the context of orthogonal polynomials on the real line, so there's probably quite a bit known. (This is probably overkill, though.)

Comment: Also, when I run this matrix in Mathematica I find that the determinant of $P$ (and therefore of $P^2$) vanishes regardless of $n$. So something seems goofy...

Comment: To formalize the issue I see: Taking the rows/columns to run as $i,j=1,2,\ldots,n$, the first row of $P$ is $(\omega^2,\omega^3,\ldots,\omega^{n+1})$ and the second row is $(\omega^3,\omega^4,\ldots,\omega^{n+2})=\omega (\omega^2,\omega^3,\ldots,\omega^{n+1})$. Hence the second row is not linearly independent of the first and so the determinant must vanish regardless of $n$.

Comment: The problem refers not to the square of the determinant, but to the square of the matrix itself, I believe it is one of the problems in the JEE (Hiss >,< ) 2013. http://jeeadv.iitr.ac.in/index.php/downloads/

Comment: As for a hint, try directly multiplying, factoring out a common term while evaluating the sum for each element, and exploit the fact that $1+ \omega + \omega ^2 = 0$

Comment: @TimTheEnchanter Yes you are correct. My bad. The problem sets in my JEE Archive just showed it as '0' instead of 'O'. Updating the question now. Really sorry for so much mistakes.

Comment: I think that one can use what @Semiclassical says in this way: $P= w w^T$  for the obvious vector $w$ and then $P^2$ is clearly the multiple of $P$ by the scalar [end of hint]

Comment: @TimTheEnchanter How do I direct multiply. I have learnt the determinants of only $3\times3$ matrices